# XCode - Passing real ID or array to second tableview and not array ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

In my XCode (IOS) I populate a tableview from information received of a url

```
myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *URL_json = @"http://localhost/info.php";

NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL URLWithString:URL_json]];

id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSString *id_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"my_id"];
    NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"my_title"];
    NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"my_icon"];

    dictionaryA = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     id_data, my_id,
                     title_data, my_title,
                     thumbnail_data, my_icon,
                     nil];
    [myObject addObject:dictionaryA];
}
```

What I would like to do is for the second table view to receive the **real ID** (coming from the URL and passed to myObject) of the clicked row and not the indexPath ID that is sent (objectAtIndex:indexPath.row) when using the following:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSecond"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    SecondViewController *List = segue.destinationViewController;
    List.myinfo = [myObjectCat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: You are sending NSDictionary to `SecondViewController` on table row click, in `SecondViewController` you can get the **realID** as you want from the NSDictionary. What's the problem?

Comment: I am sending objectAtIndex:indexPath.row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSecond"]){
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    SecondViewController *List = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSDictionary *dict = [myObjectCat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    List.info = [dict objectForKey@"my_id"];//passing real id
  }
}
```